# how to define a stored procedures which accepts 2 parameteres

Tags: mysql, statements, procedures

I´m trying to define a stored procedures which accepts 2 parameteres , one would be the table column which has to be equal with the second parameter i will provide.
Code :

```
 DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectUserByField`(IN _field varchar(150) , IN _value varchar(150))
    BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE', _field, '=' ,_value);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END
```

The thing is that i don´t know how to provide the _value param as a string. If i run it like this i get a Mysql 1064 near ´=myEmail´( params where ´userEmail´,´myEmail´). Thanks !

Comment: You are preparing twice. Which one are you executing?

Comment: you´re right, i made an edit, that was another query for test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your below code, you are missing a space after `WHERE`. It should be like below; give a space after `WHERE` and in `=`

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ', _field, ' = ' ,_value);
```

Comment: Are you certain that, you used the exact code posted in answer; cause now the query will be formed like `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userEmail = myEmail` which should work just fine; whereas in your posted code the query was getting formed as `SELECT * FROM Users WHEREuserEmail = myEmail` and so you were getting 1064 syntax error. If there is something other than what you have posted in question then that's a blackbox for me.

Comment: CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ', _field, ' = ' ,_value);

Comment: i managed to get it to work for numeric values like ID, but when i access it with string it doesn´t return anything

Comment: Do you know any method to tell mysql that 'myEmail' is a string ?

Comment: My final query that works fine for everything is : SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ',  _field, ' = ' , '"', _value, '"');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;